# Row, Column, Diagonal, Block

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, source-layout

Write a square block of code that is N characters wide and N characters tall, for some positive integer N.

For instance, your N may be 5 and the block look like this:

```
ThisI
sMy5B
y5Cod
eBloc
kOkay
```

This block needs to behave as follows:

1. When the top row is extracted and run as a program, the exact text `row` needs to be printed to stdout.

   For example, `ThisI` would print `row`.
2. When the left column is extracted and run as a program, the exact text `col` needs to be printed to stdout.

   For example, `Tsyek` would print `col`.
3. When the main diagonal from the top left to the bottom right corners is extracted and run as a program, the exact text `dia` needs to be printed to stdout.

   For example, `TMCoy` would print `dia`.
4. When the entire block is run as a program, **including the newlines** (with an optional trailing newline), the exact text `blk` needs to be printed to stdout.

   For example,

   ```
   ThisI
   sMy5B
   y5Cod
   eBloc
   kOkay
   ```

   would print `blk`.

**Details**

- All four programs are run in the same programming language.
- The N<sup>2</sup> characters in the original block may be anything but [line terminators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode).
- If your language does not have an stdout, you may use another common output method. It must be the same method across all four programs.

**The submission whose original block contains the fewest distinct characters (not counting newlines) wins.** Tiebreaker goes to the submission with the smaller N.

Comment: Given that there's surely a solution in some two-symbol esoteric language, I think this will become a solution to squeeze that into the smallest N.

Comment: @xnor Probably. Though a 1-distinct [Lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage) answer is not out of the realm of possibility. Still, this scoring method is more interesting than having smallest N win first.

Comment: How can Lenguage work given that the row and column programs have the same length?

Comment: @xnor Ah, you're right. It wouldn't work.

Comment: Can non-block programs also end with a trailing newline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [><> (Fish)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 3 unique characters (N = 2000)

The code uses `1` and `-` to put arbitrary numbers on the stack and `p` to (self-)modify the code based on the top 3 numbers on the stack.
E.g Putting a `!` at position `0 0` would look like `003b*p` in normal ><> and with `p1-` it becomes `111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1--11-11-p`.

After the modification the instruction pointer (IP) wraps around the code and runs the modified part. In the "block" case the IP is redirected for further modification (then reredirected back) to differ from the "row" case. In the "row" case the same two redirection happens but there is no code in between them so they have no effect.

The final generated codes for the 4 cases (omitting the unchanged `p1-` parts):

```
row:      "wor"\ooo;

column:   "loc"ooo;

diagonal: "dia"ooo;

block:    "wor"\"klb"ooo;
```

The code size is 4 MB and the code is accessible [here](http://pastee.co/0IwyR0/raw). (There is no difficulty running it.)

The generator python3 program is accessible [here](http://ideone.com/AFVTDz).

Answer (score 14):

## CJam, <s>13</s> 12 unique characters, N = 5

```
"row"
cd;"a
oaiaa
l"aa;
"blk"
```

As straight forward as it gets

*UPDATE* : Converted space to `a` (no-op in this case) as pointed out by Runner112

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22row%22%0Acd%3B%22%0Ao%20i%0Al%22%20a%3B%0A%22blk%22)

Comment: Every space can be turned into a character like `a` to bring the unique character count down to 12, right?

Comment: @Runer112 Damn! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 8):

## Bash, 19 unique characters, N = 19

```
trap echo\ row exit
t=t trap exit      
t=t echo blk       
exit               
=                  
t    e             
      c            
e      h           
c       o          
h                  
o         d        
           i       
c           a      
o                  
l
```

- The first row is `trap echo\ row exit`.  This causes `echo row` to be executed when the script exits (just the first line)
- The first column is `ttt=t echo col`
- The diagonal is `t=tt echo dia`
- The full block works by canceling the EXIT handler set up in the first line, then `echo blk` then exits.

Comment: You can use lowercase `exit` to reduce unique characters by 4. You can also move the `exit` command to the next line and replace all the semicolons with spaces.

Answer (score 6):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 14 unique characters, N = 10

```
"wor"\ooo;
     "    
l a  k    
o  i l    
c   db    
"    "    
o    oo   
o    o o  
o    o  o 
;    ;   ;
```

Pretty straightforward in a 2D language. The only tricky part is that we need the `\` to distinguish between `row` and `blk`.

Comment: randomra notes that `p1-` would give a three char solution, but it would be really annoying to generate (and probably won't win).

Answer (score 3):

## Brainfuck, 2 unique characters, N = 378

*With possible slight bending of rules.*

The program is a tad large, so here's a [link to it on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/RvidCEV8).

The `row`, `col` and `dia` programs are straightforward. They simply increment the byte cell until the right ASCII code is reached and then outputs. If the letter has already passed, it increments until the cell overflows so it can start again at 0.

The `blk` program is where the slight rule bending occurs. In order to print the "exact text `blk`" as asked in the challenge, backspaces are used (ASCII code 8), which requires the displaying console/terminal to support it. Whenever errant values from the `row`/`col`/`dia` programs are printed, I ensure they are removed by outputting a few backspace control codes. To simplify things, I've ensured that all errant values outputted at one point are part of the printable ASCII range.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 26 unique chars, N = 29

```c
*w;main(){printf(w?w:"row");}
ww;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;/*;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
m;;m;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
a;;;a;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
i;;;;i;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
n;;;;;n;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(;;;;;;(;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
);;;;;;;);;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
{;;;;;;;;{;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
p;;;;;;;;;p;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
r;;;;;;;;;;r;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
i;;;;;;;;;;;i;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
n;;;;;;;;;;;;n;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
t;;;;;;;;;;;;;t;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
f;;;;;;;;;;;;;;f;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;(;;;;;;;;;;;;
";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;";;;;;;;;;;;
c;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;d;;;;;;;;;;
o;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;i;;;;;;;;;
l;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;a;;;;;;;;
";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;";;;;;;;
);;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;);;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
};;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;};;*/
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;*w="blk";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZHPCsMgDMbveQxPKozeF8aexTk6ZK0tUsih9Nldu/V/zXbZB2riD4lfYk8Pa2PUhKVxXqq2Ds43uaQrnUWoSCjsgAh5Qb8yzdISseTfmn4zLHXD7jjq34dnqPycMk3VGKgkbaeoTdF6DusEDUscGEejHONo1N4YNJu02dF8m@fJbsza5CD2P1lfgD3YuK9odezBYgyKRAMNX3ddG5KzmSYG@E3QMaC/19mPt/@mmi7iVjwFxvgC)

Answer (score 2):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 11 unique characters, N=6

```
irow␛␛
cdddd␛
o␛i␛␛␛
l␛␛a␛␛
␛kdd␛␛
␛iblk␛
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P7Mov9wmtTjZDkxwJacAAYSZD6YyEZIQ4RwEOxFJGExmQ/UiCWUm5WSDGf///9ctAwA)

lot of escapes here. N=5 might be achievable, but I can't see a way to do it without increasing the unique characters.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 24 unique chars, N=17

```ruby
trap(0){$><<:row}
rr=a=:blk;%;00000
a0a00000000000000
p00p0000000000000
(000(000000000000
00000000000000000
)00000)0000000000
{000000{000000000
$0000000$00000000
>00000000>0000000
<000000000<000000
<0000000000<00000
:00000000000:0000
c000000000000d000
o0000000000000i00
l;;trap(0){$><<a;
};000000000000;{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBBC4MwDIXv@R0dtLecm@p/idtlTLAERaT0t3fq1KXbOySPjwd5RKZuKWUUjhZdMm0IXoY5g0jDje/6F90INwEjYyWIiLEmdh22IvgrcPtyiqTPTl9iDmMu0p7uNBCuePgjBwKvDu8e7rrLYyNDVe@5kp5IP4QJMukMpVzKGw)